# What are the steps in submitting an R-package to CRAN and how long does each step take?

Tags: r, cran

I have noticed that once submitted to incoming (ftp://cran.r-project.org/incoming) the package name receives the following suffixes .save, .pending and .noemail. Then, the package disappears from incoming. I suppose the next step is that the CRAN maintainers put it on the main server (http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/ http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/) and then it gets propagated to the mirrors.

My questions:

(1)Could someone confirm the steps and provide detail on them. Especially what happens after the package disappears from incoming (didn't find a way to check status for that step)

(2) how long does each step take on average?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you think this forum is preferable to r-devel? To my knowledge the CRAN maintainers don't read this, so you get second knowledge at best.

Comment: you've read section 1.5 in the *R extensions manual* (http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Submitting-a-package-to-CRAN) **really** carefully, right?  (It doesn't answer your question, but the CRAN maintainers are very picky and so it's worth reading in great detail to avoid frustration ...)

Answer (score 9):

All the public info about CRAN policies is here:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html

if the info you seek is not there, then only the Gods of CRAN know it. I wouldn't rely on those suffixes having any great meaning to us. That would be CRAN's internal processing, which might change at the whims of the Gods of CRAN.

The answer to question 2 is the same answer to 'how long is a piece of string?'.